# A movie(European I believe) about a man wanting to die, but meeting a woman and changing his mind

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie in May of 2016 on a flight from Belgium to the US. I am fairly certain it is European(English-speaking), and was released sometime in 2015-2016.

The gist of the story was a man, probably in his 40's, whose mother passed away, and he decided he didn't want to live anymore. He was very wealthy and had a nice house with a fairly large car collection. To accomplish this feat of dying, he finds a company that essentially does assisted suicides, you sign up and they kill you randomly in the near future.

While he was signing up for this service, he meets a female who also appears to be signing up for this service. They end up hitting it off, he falls in love with her and changes his mind about wanting to die. The only problem is he isn't able to cancel his original contract for being killed.

**Spoiler** (but potentially helpful)

> It turned out the woman he met was the daughter of the guy who owned the company he contracted his death through. I think she was the one who was supposed to kill him, but this might be wrong.

It's not *I Hired a Contract Killer (1990)*.

Comment: European covers a lot of ground. Could you narrow down a language?

Comment: @Paulie_D It was in English, I added this to the question

Comment: Was it black and white ?? What year do you think it was made?? I know you watched it in 2016 but what was the movie quality??

Comment: I put in the post I believe it came out around 2016. The quality is high, and I'm extremely confident it was released in either 2015 or 2016. Adding this to the question as well

Comment: How old was the main character? Old, young...? Around 30ies? Do you remember from which country to which country you were flying? Often they give movies according to theses (since they are more likely to be watch/match the taste of the users)?

Comment: The main character was probably in his 40's. It was a Belgium airline. Adding these to the question as well.

Comment: Finally, a good question!

Comment: sounds like a good plot....someone please identify the movie...i also want to watch it now!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Surprise](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt3409440/), from 2015.

> After both signing an agreement with a company that offers to end their lives when they least expect it, a dejected millionaire and a disheartened young woman fall in love and have to find a way to get out of their binding contracts.

Comment: This is it! Thank you, I thought the story line was pretty interesting, wanted to give it another watch.